# Group/Sort Data using helper column

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, grouping

I'm looking to find a way to group/sort data based on a 2 serial numbers, in this case called Demand Number and Supply Number.

The logic I'm trying to apply is if an items supply number matches the demand number of another item then it should be shown underneath it for example if you were to sort the data shown below:

[image: Raw Data]

You would get the following result:

[image: Sort 1]

I think I will need to use some helper columns, to apply 'levels' to the items but I'm really not sure where to go.

Thanks for the help!!

Note if there is not way to achieve the sort as shown above, this sort would also be suitable:

[image: Sort 2]

Here is the data as text:

```
 Item   ID  Demand Number   Supply Number
Nut 10  1005    10055
Nut 10  10056   10087
Nut 10  1005    100585
Washer  40  10056   10095
Washer  40  1005    154899
Suspension  9   1001    1005
Engine  15  1001    10056
Car 66  18996   1001
```

Comment: pivot table perhaps?

Comment: can you paste that sample data (First Table) in the question ? ... Oh! I see now you have edited your question. If you can have the second option as you mentioned, is this question still valid?

Comment: Hi @Mech that does give the sort I want, the problem is in following columns I have associated start and end dates which I want to stay shown that I can only show as count values when I use a pivot table.

Comment: Hi @NareshBhople I would very much prefer the first sort, however even with the second sort I believe the question is still valid as there will be multiple entries like this so if I only sort by demand order there is nothing to ensure only supply orders eventually linked to that demand order appear below it.